# Can't share a photo in Facebook from Android app

Tags: java, android, facebook

I am trying to share a photo on Facebook from an Android application. I take the image from the gallery and create a bitmap with it, which I then send to Facebook with the `setShareContent` method.

When you run the app, the log says this:

> Unexpected activity pause without a matching activity resume. Logging data may be incorrect. Make sure you call `activateApp` from your Application's `onCreate()` method.

I have the following code:

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ShareButton shareButton;
    FloatingActionButton selectImageFromGalleryBtn;
    Bitmap bitmap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        shareButton = (ShareButton) findViewById(R.id.shareButton);
        selectImageFromGalleryBtn = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.selectImageFromGalleryBtn);

        selectImageFromGalleryBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
            }
        });

        SharePhoto photo = new SharePhoto.Builder()
            .setBitmap(bitmap)
            .build();

        SharePhotoContent content = new SharePhotoContent.Builder()
            .addPhoto(photo)
            .build();

        shareButton.setShareContent(content);
    }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.dchurches.sharevideofacebook">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/MyMaterialTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>

        <provider
               android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProviderXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
            android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"
            android:exported="true"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I followed the Facebook developers documentation to share a photo, but it does not seem to work. Can anybody help me? Thanks in advance

Comment: post your application class (i.e class that extends Application)

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a class that extends application and initialize FB and Logger as below

```
public class AppCtrl extends Application {

@Override
public void onCreate() {
   super.onCreate();
   // Initialize the SDK before executing any other operations,
   FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
   AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this);
   }   
}
```

and define this class in manifest's application tag as below

```
    <application android:name="AppCtrl"
       ...>
    </application>
```

Comment: It's tried and it does not work. Anyway, according to the official documentation, in the latest versions of the Facebook SDK, specifically from 4.x, it is not necessary to initialize the SDK explicitly, it starts automatically. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: did u try adding this line   AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this);? because your error says to add this

Comment: Yes, I added that line, but Android Studio sets the activateApp method as deprecated, and nothing change in execution